# ISO-8859-1 encoded strings out of /into JSON in Java

Tags: java, json, iso-8859-1

My application has a Java servlet that reads a JSONObject out of the request and constructs some Java objects that are used elsewhere.  I'm running into a problem because there are strings in the JSON that are encoded in ISO-8859-1.  When I extract them into Java strings, the encoding appears to get interpreted as UTF-16.  I need to be able to get the correctly encoded string back at some point to put into another JSON object.

I've tried mucking around with ByteBuffers and CharBuffers, but then I don't get any characters at all.  I can't change the encoding, as I have to play nicely with other applications that use ISO-8859-1.

Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

It's a legacy application using Struts 1.3.8.  I'm using net.sf.json 2.2.4 for JSONObject and JSONArray.

A snippet of the parsing code is:

```
final JSONObject a = (JSONObject) i;
final JSONObject attr = a.getJSONObject("attribute");
final String category = attr.getString("category");

final String value = attr.getString("value");
```

I then create POJOs using that information, that are retrieved by another action class to create JSON to pass to the client for display, or to pass to other applications.

So to clarify, if the JSON contains the string "Juan Guzmán", the Java String contains something like Juan Guzm?_An (I don't have the exact one in front of me).  I'm not sure how to get the correct diacritical back.  I believe that if I can get a Java String that contains the correct representation, that Mezzie's solution, below, will allow me to create the string with the correct encoding to put back into the JSON to serve back.

Comment: Hi Betsey, and welcome to Stack Overflow. You need to provide a bit more information here. Maybe you could paste some of the code that does the reading? Or at least state which frameworks/libraries you are using for this task.

Comment: @AleksanderBlomskøld, I added a little detail above, hopefully that helps.  Thank you for your quick response!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue and I am using the same technology as you are. In our case, it was UTF 8. so just change that to UTF-16

```
    public static String UTF8toISO( String str )
    {
        try
        {
            return new String( str.getBytes( "ISO-8859-1" ), "UTF-8" );
        }
        catch ( UnsupportedEncodingException e )
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return str;
    }
```

Comment: Hi @mezzie, thank you for your response.  I'm a little confused, though.  When I read the data out of the JSON, it get represented incorrectly in the Java string, because Java, by default, encodes them as UTF16.  I think your method above will work to get an ISO-8859-1 encoded string out of a properly-formed Java string, but I don't believe it solves the original half of my problem.

Comment: Hi Betsey, there are a few things that you might want to look at. Java does not by default encode string to UTF16. The question is why it is encoding it to UTF 16. How are the request passed to your sevlet? Is it through ajax? if so, then you might need to set the character encoding there so that you do not have to deal with decoding it in the backend. If you do not have control over the data that is passed in the backend, then decoding it with this method should help.

Comment: Hi mezzie, according to the Javadocs, Java does, by default, encode the strings to UTF-16, at least in 1.6 (the version I have to use):
A String represents a string in the UTF-16 format in which supplementary characters are represented by surrogate pairs (see the section Unicode Character Representations in the Character class for more information). Index values refer to char code units, so a supplementary character uses two positions in a String.  
I think I've solved part of the problem; there's just a few places I've missed at this point and I am tracking them down.  Thanks!

Comment: I figured it out.  I just grab the bytes from the UTF-16 String, and convert to a correctly encoded string using @mezzie's method, above.Thanks!!